# How is JetBrains IntelliJ accessing my GitHub account to push changes?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, ssh

I created a new test project in IntelliJ, brought it under VCS, and then assigned a remote to a public GitHub repository (https://github.com/BrianHVB/GitTest1)

Any time I push out changes from within IntelliJ (VCS | Git | Push), the operation completes successfully and I can log into my GitHub page and see the updates.

However, I don't understand how IntelliJ is accessing the remote repository given the following:

- There are no SSH or GPG keys associated with my GitHub account
- There are no public or private keys in my ~/.SSH folder.
- I have not entered my GitHub credentials into IntelliJ
- I don't think I've entered anything other than my email address into any local Git settings
- I've logged out of GitHub on my browser.

[image]

[image]

Also, I can't seem to find any IntelliJ option for setting or configuring remote repositories. According to [IntelliJ's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/managing-remotes.html), there should be a VCS | Git | Remotes tool. However, there is no "Remotes" option from my VCS | Git window, and no Git Remotes or Remotes tool or action from the global tool search (ctrl+shift+a).

[image]

How can I access or change my remote repo settings for my IntelliJ project, and how can I add some kind of authentication requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have assigned it to an https url, ssh does not matter.

Check in command line what [`git config credential.helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) returns: you might have cached your `github.com` credential a long time ago, in which case IntelliJ and its `git push` call would get your credential from a Credential Manager.

IntelliJ itself knows how to **[handle Passwords for Git Remote Repositories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/handling-passwords-for-git-remote-repositories.html)**

> IntelliJ IDEA provides the ability to [configure a password policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/handling-passwords-for-git-remote-repositories.html#passwordPolicy) according to which passwords are either never saved, or saved during one session and cleared upon the session end, or stored in a special passwords database.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Apparently, when I installed the Windows GitHub Git client, it also installed the https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows, which stored my username and password in my Windows Credential Store. The client also configured my GitHub account to allow access tokens to be used as a login, which is why I never remembered entering my password into the Credential Store.

Still not sure why IntelliJ isn't giving me the option to configure remote repositories though.

Answer (score -2):

This is a sh*tty twist from GitHub, and what I mad about most is that I got freaking 0 (ZERO!) notifications about the fact that this change is gonna take place on 22nd of Feb 2018.

Installing credentials manager over older versions of git doesn't help.

What helps:

- a) uninstall your current git
- b) install lastest git https://git-scm.com/download/, it contains credential manager
- c) in Intellij IDEA go to File->Settings->Version Control->Git, show to IDEA where new git.exe is
- d) after that do a test commit and try to push: it should open new window for github signup
- e) set your credentials there and all should be fine

Comment: I'm not sure what change you are referring to. This question was originally posted over a year ago. What took place on Feb 22?